# Angular 5 AsyncValidator Leaves Control With Status:PENDING

Tags: angular, forms, rxjs

I have not been able to successfully utilise an AsyncValidator function on a Reactive Form, and need assistance to understand the reason why.

The **validator function** is:

```
export function checkVoiceNumberExists(): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (c: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
        return (c.value === null) ? Observable.of(null) : ValidMobileNumbers.checkVoiceNumberExists(c.value)
            .map(results => {
                return Observable.of(results.length === 1 ? null
                    : { 'invalidMobileNotListed': 'This mobile number does not exist in the validation list' }
                );
            }
            );
    }
}
```

My **typescript form component** imports and uses the function as follows:

```
import { checkVoiceNumberExists, checkVoiceNumberNotAllocated } from 'common/validators/company-mobile-numbers';

let fctrl_voice: FormControl = new FormControl(
    '',
    [SabreFormControlValidators.hasLeadingZero, SabreFormControlValidators.isTelephoneNumber],
    [checkVoiceNumberExists(), checkVoiceNumberNotAllocated(empID)]
);
```

I am seeing that an error should be returned, in the following debug output:

```
Object {invalidMobileNotListed: "This mobile number does not exist in the validatio…"}
invalidMobileNotListed:"This mobile number does not exist in the validation list"
```

However, the STATUS of the form control remains at PENDING, as seen here:

```
<input _ngcontent-c9="" class="form-control ng-dirty ng-pending ng-touched" maxlength="11" ng-reflect-maxlength="11" ng-reflect-name="emp_telno_company" id="emp_telno_company">
```

**I would expect to see ng-invalid rather than ng-pending**

Due to this problem

- my CSS error class is not being applied to the control
- the form STATUS is showing as PENDING

I have tried altering the validator function with a minor alteration,  as follows:

```
export function checkVoiceNumberExists(): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (c: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors | null> => {
        return (c.value === null) ? Observable.of(null) : ValidMobileNumbers.checkVoiceNumberExists(c.value)
            .map(results => {
                return results.length === 1 ? null : { 'invalidMobileNotListed': 'This mobile number does not exist in the validation list' };
            });
    }
}
```

What do I need to do to correctly pick up a validation error in this situation?

Comment: Are you sure `ValidMobileNumbers.checkVoiceNumberExists` returns an Observable that completes?

Comment: The second implementation of `checkVoiceNumberExists()` looks right. But as martin says you need to check if `ValidMobileNumbers.checkVoiceNumberExists` returns an observable which emits data.

Comment: @martin @BharatGupta Thanks - I can subscribe to the `checkInvoiceNumberExists()` and display a response as here:

`ValidMobileNumber.checkVoiceNumberExists('07392870397').subscribe(
            (response) => {
                console.log(response);
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            }
        );
Array(1) length:1
0:Object {vamob_ID: "124", vamob_number: "07392.......", vamob_type: "V", …}`
So it does seem fine to me. Would you agree with that test?

Comment: Sorry, typo `checkInvoiceNumberExists()`  should read `checkVoiceNumberExists()`

Comment: It seems to me now that the problem is due to the presence of multiple AsyncValidators against the one FormControl. I have this: `let fctrl_voice: FormControl = new FormControl( '', [SabreFormControlValidators.hasLeadingZero, SabreFormControlValidators.isTelephoneNumber], [checkVoiceNumberExists(), checkVoiceNumberNotAllocated(empID)] );` 
When I remove the second asyncval, the first one works. If I remove the first, the second one works! **What's that all about? **